# Delegating to threads while preserving linear readability

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, completable-future

I've been experimenting with different ways to handle blocking methods with disconnected results while maintaining state which might have been interrupted. I've found it to be frustrating having to deal with disparate classes and methods where sending and receiving are difficult to align.

In the following example, `SomeBlockingMethod()` normally returns `void` as a message is sent to some other process. But instead I've made it `synchronized` with a listener which receives the result. By spinning it off to a thread, I can `wait()` for the result with a timeout or indefinitely.

This is nice because once the result is returned, I can continue working with a particular state which I had to pause while waiting for the result of the threaded task.

This there anything wrong with my approach?

Although this question may seem generic, I am specifically looking for advice on threading in **Java**.

Example pseudocode:

```
public class SomeClass implements Command {

@Override
public void onCommand() {
   Object stateObject = new SomeObjectWithState();

   // Do things with stateObject

   Runnable rasync = () -> {
      Object r = SomeBlockingMethod();

      // Blocking method timed out
      if (r == null)
         return;

      Runnable rsync = () -> {
         // Continue operation on r which must be done synchronously

         // Also do things with stateObject
      };

      Scheduler().run(rsync);
   };

   Scheduler().run(rasync);
}
```

Update with CompletableFuture:

```
CompletableFuture<Object> f = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
   return SomeBlockingMethod();
});

f.thenRun(() -> { () -> {
   String r = null;

   try {
      r = f.get();
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }

   // Continue but done asynchronously
});
```

or better yet:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
   return SomeBlockingMethod();
}).thenAccept((
   Object r) -> {

   // Continue but done asynchronously
});
```

The problem with using strictly `CompletableFuture` is that `CompletableFuture.thenAccept` is run from the global thread pool and is not guaranteed to be synchronous with the calling thread.

Adding the scheduler back for the synchronous task fixes this:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
   return SomeBlockingMethod();
}).thenAccept((
   Object r) -> {

   Runnable rsync = () -> {
      // Continue operation on r which must be done synchronously
   };

   Scheduler().run(rsync);
});
```

A caveat of using `CompletableFuture` compared to the complete scheduler method is that any previous state which exists outside must be final or effectively final.

Comment: CompletableFuture solves this problem. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html

Comment: AdamSkywalker, I have done a lot of research into `CompletableFuture` since reviewing your comment and it has completely revolutionized how I approach asynchronous tasks in Java. Please submit this as an answer so that I can reward you for the assistance.

Comment: “to be synchronous with the calling thread” is an obvious contradiction to asynchronous processing. If you want to continue with the processing on the calling thread, there is no way around waiting for the result at some point in the calling thread. Which is also the simplest solution.

Comment: You're right, but the value of spinning up a bunch of asynchronous threads here and then waiting at the very end means that I can queue up several tasks that can be run in parallel but must complete within the current thread. This is much faster than performing each task in sequence, especially when there can be a significant delay, such as sending and receiving network packets.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki), it uses stream manipulation and has threading support.

```
api.getPeople()
  .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
  .filter(p -> return p.isEmployee();)
  .map(p -> return String.format("%s %s - %s", p.firstName(), p.lastName(), p.payrollNumber());)
  .toList()
  .observerOn(<ui scheudler>)
  .subscirbe(p -> screen.setEmployees(p);)
```